# Android Annotations Login Failed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, restful-authentication, http-status-code-401, android-annotations

I am using Android Annotations to manage my client-webservice communication.

When I try to login to an endpoint with AA I get 401 Unauthorized error, but I can successfully login to that endpoint and get a response when I use Postman.

My Rest Client code is like this:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = NetworkConstants.BASE_URL, converters = {GsonHttpMessageConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class},
    interceptors = {RestAuthInterceptor.class})
public interface RestClient extends RestClientHeaders, RestClientErrorHandling {

@Post(NetworkConstants.OFFICER_LOGIN)
LoginModel loginOfficer(LoginModel.LoginRequest request);
}
```

And my Login Model is like this:

```
public class LoginModel {

@SerializedName("id")
public String id;

@SerializedName("ttl")
public int ttl;

@SerializedName("userId")
public int userId;

@SerializedName("created")
public Date created;

public static class LoginRequest {
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    public String password;
}
}
```

And the url I am using is like this:

```
  public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.com/api/";


  public static final String LOGIN = "login";
```

And the Interceptor class I am using is like this:

```
@EBean(scope = EBean.Scope.Singleton)
public class RestAuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Override
public org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    HttpAuthentication auth = new HttpBasicAuthentication("emailadress", "password");
    headers.setAuthorization(auth);
    return execution.execute(request, body);

}
}
```

As I said earlier, when I use these values on Postman, I got a successful response, but when I try this within the app, I got a 401 error.

I have tried some solutions and tried to add BasicHttpAuth within the interceptor but did not work, I wonder if that is a common problem or is there a problem with the API.

Note:The API endpoint urls and header values in the Interceptor class in the question are not the real values, I have changed them for the sake of privacy.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code seems to be OK. Try to log the request with [this](https://gist.github.com/WonderCsabo/75cea06360a8faab304b) request factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my code was ok and the problem was in the back-end, thanks